# What is wrong with my spawnspots?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a multiplayer game and in my program there is a `spawnSpots` code that I made and it's saying that it doesn't exist but it clearly does.

Here's the code:

```
void Start()
{
    spawnSpots = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<SpawnSpot>();
}
```

Then there is:

```
if(spawnSpots == null)
{
    Debug.LogError("No Spawns Placed.");
    return;
}

SpawnSpot mySpawnSpot = spawnSpots[Random.Range (0, spawnSpots.length)];
```

So everytime the word spawSpots is written, the error is saying:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'spawnSpots' does not exist in the current context Multiplayer-FPS.CSharp  C:\Users\desha\Documents\Multiplayer-FPS\Assets\NetworkManager.cs   15  Active

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show more code? Is `spawnSpots` declared as a proprety in your script? The error seems to hint that `spawnSpots` does not exist in the current context, that is, that it was never declared?

Answer (score 2):

Ok if you are setting up a networked multiplayer game then you will need to have a NetworkStartPosition component on each of your spawn point in the scene.

[image]

It is also worth noting that the NetworkManager you would need in your scene also has some spawn settings. Including a spawn method, which if you select "round robin" will randomly spawn players at each of your NetworkStartPositions for you.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Here is a link to an excellent video covering the basics of network multiplayer. It is by far the most useful I have found. [UnityNetworkTutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6wEvT6G92M)

Comment: There is a unity assets package you would need to import. This comes standard with the newer version. But if you don't have it, you can download a free lobby manager from the assets store here https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/41836

Comment: Would i just create an empty? or would i put it in the spawnpoint aswell?

Comment: I have edited my answer with an extra resource, a link to video tutorial which explains the basics very well and I believe it will help you achieve what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

You are using GameObject.FindObjectOfType incorrectly, it looks like you want to set up an array then pick a random one. Lookup arrays, how to add to the array.

find object of type: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I'm just trying to have the player land on a random spawn spot.

Comment: It does answer your question, if you use the correct way to do things from the start it will be easier to diagnose what you are trying to do. I think you should go through the networking help on the Unity wiki https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNet.html